# cannot implement run() in Runnable

Tags: java, multithreading

```
public class Reader extends Thread{

...

    public static void run()throws InterruptedException{

        Monitor mon = new Monitor();

            for(int i = 0; i <10; i++)
            {
                mon.MonEntry();



                Read("file.txt");

                mon.MonExit();
            }

    }
}
```

I cannot use extends Thread for some reason because it says: cannot implement run() in Runnable. I don't see what I did wrong? When we call extends Thread instead of implement Runnable shouldn't we be able to use our own implementation of run() for starting threads?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is just a public void. No static.

Please, have a look at the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#run%28%29). It clearly shows that it is `public void` :-)

Also, avoid the name `Reader` because there is a class in `java.io` package which is named `Reader` and using names that are already present in Java packages is discouraged :)

Comment: get rid of the `Exception` and see. :)

Comment: error: unreported exception InterruptedException; must be caught or declared to be thrown

Comment: yes so where you are calling the run method, surround it with try and catch.

Comment: i am curious... why can't we throw it instead, is it because when we interrupt a native hread we may damage the system or something?

Comment: Because `run()` as of itself does not throw any exception. If you declare that it throws something, you are going against the signature. Hence the issue :)

Answer (score 1):

`run` method inside Thread class is not static